# Local complete intersection and hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors, hypersurfaces

Let $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a regular, codimension $2$, complete intersection subscheme in $\mathbb{P}^n$ (for example, $Y \cong \mathbb{P}^{n-2}$). Let $X$ be a normal (not necessarily smooth) hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ containing $Y$. Is $Y$ a Cartier divisor in $X$?

Comment: The short answer is, in general no. If $Y$ is the complete intersection of $F=G=0$, then any such $X$ is of the form $AF+BG=0$. Thus, for example, at the set  of points where all the $A,F,B,G$ vanish, $Y$ is not a Cartier divisor on $X$.

Comment: Let $X$ be a quadric (or higher degree) cone in $\mathbb P^3$ and $Y$ a line through the cone point. Then $Y\simeq \mathbb P^{3-2}$ but it is not a Cartier divisor on $X$.

Comment: In fact it seems Y is a Cartier divisor if and only if X is smooth along Y - see Mumford's rebook, chapter III.7, Prop. 2, p.195 of the second expanded Springer edition, LNM 1358.